the problem of importing the load_model library from tensorflow
I'm trying to import a library:
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model.

But I get the following error:

ANOM_ABEND auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 pid=3489 comm="python" exe="/usr/bin/python3.11" sig=4 res=1**

I tried to import the tensorflow library. The rest of the libraries work and are imported correctly. I couldn't find information on this error on the Internet, I hope that someone will help me figure it out.

It seems TensorFlow isn't working correctly on your system. This could be due to a problem with the TensorFlow installation or  compatibility issue with your Python version. Ensure TensorFlow's compatibility with your system's architecture (CPU or GPU) and reinstall if necessary to fix the issue. If the issue still persists, Please let me know.
